# dlopen failed has text relocations

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to use an npm package on my react-native project and I get this error. I don't really know how to approach this error and don't recognize the path "/data/app/com.workandroidpls-WCrWjZAlFq2u_5qcJd-mrA==/lib/x86/libagora-rtc-sdk-jni.so". I'm using the react-native-agora npm package on react native 57.4.

Could not invoke RCTAgora.init

null

dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.workandroidpls-WCrWjZAlFq2u_5qcJd-mrA==/lib/x86/libagora-rtc-sdk-jni.so" has text relocations (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/android-changes-for-ndk-developers.md#Text-Relocations-Enforced-for-API-level-23)
invoke
    JavaMethodWrapper.java:383
invoke
    JavaModuleWrapper.java:160
run
    NativeRunnable.java
handleCallback
    Handler.java:873
dispatchMessage
    Handler.java:99
dispatchMessage
    MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29
loop
    Looper.java:193
run
    MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:192
run
    Thread.java:764